# Django migrations RunPython reverse function

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

In the documentation there is a mention of a reverse function in RunPython in django migrations https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/migration-operations/#runpython
When does the reverse function run?
Is there a specific command to run the reverse function?

Comment: When you migrate backwards e.g. to `zero` or a specific migration.

Comment: If your last migration has number let's say 0017, you can reverse migration by running `python manage.py migrate <app_name> 0016`